# python ftp cant delete file, while lftp can

Tags: python, ftp

I'm trying to delete file from FTP server using python's `ftp` lib (I do have R/W permission):

```py
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('192.168.1.2')
ftp.login(user='admin', passwd=None)
ftp.login()

ftp.cwd('audio/user_rec/575B62E2')
ftp.dir()
```

Output:

```
d---------   1 owner nogroup          0 Oct 27 12:23 .
d---------   1 owner nogroup          0 Oct 27 12:23 ..
----------   1 owner nogroup      16120 Oct 27 12:23 2023-10-27_12-23-04.wav
----------   1 owner nogroup      10680 Oct 27 12:23 2023-10-27_12-23-05.wav
```

When I try to `ftp.delete('2023-10-27_12-23-04.wav')`, I get: `error_perm: 550 Request action not taken.`

But when I use `lftp` with the same password and the same FTP commands (DELE, sniffed with wireshark) I get file deleted successfully

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: gosh, it was strange authorization problem: `passwd=None` does not work, but `passwd=''` does

Comment: Maybe some background information about the difference between [None vs empty string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519647/) ...

Comment: @banderlog013 Are you sure about that? Haven't you changed something else? Both `""` and `None` result in `*put* 'PASS \r\n'` – no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl absolutely, nothing else was changed. On that server exist anonymous user without password with only 'read' rights. Maybe because of this